# Will I be charged any fees to use iTunes Radio with my AT&T unlimited data plan?

Tags: ios, cellular-data, cellular-carriers, itunes-radio

I just got an iPhone 5s. My wireless plan is with AT&T and includes unlimited cellular data. When I open the Music app and go to iTunes Radio, a dialog appears stating:

> Use Cellular Data?
>
> Additional fees may apply when using cellular data
>   for iTunes Radio, iTunes Match, and Automatic Downloads.

Is AT&T charging additional fees for using these services, or is this dialog only warning about the high rate of data usage that may cause limited-data subscribers to exceed their monthly data allowances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you won't be charged anything extra.  The dialog is only warning you about the high data usage.

Comment: I received my bill, and it did not include any additional fees for the service. I received an SMS from AT&T that I was about to exceed 5 GB of data transfer for the month, after which my transfers would be rate-limited.